# How to use single click line editing in latest jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Single click inline row editing started from  beforeSelectRow is not working in latest free jqgrid from github master.

Clicking in row to start inline edit causes now exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined Line 16181 Column 45TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined    at showHideEditDelete
```

Open this page in chrome and press Kohe button so that it is in pressed state.
After that click in some line to start inline editing.
This exception occurs.

How to use single click inline row editing in latest free jqgrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem: you called `setFrozenColumns` **twice**. The second call some destroys internal structures. If I skip in the debugger the second call of `setFrozenColumns` then inline editing starts to work.

I posted just now [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/d5d1af9f3f46501e13d41f58cfb95c783def4e39) which will ignore the second call of `setFrozenColumns`. Nevertheless I strictly recommend you to remove the second call of `setFrozenColumns` from your code.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the issue in testcase. Now if customer list is scrolled down, inline editing  places forozen and unfrosen columns to different horizontal positions and actions buttons are not changed to save and cancel buttons. If inline editing is started without scrolling, it starts properly.

Comment: I posted [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/aaad5aa9965f4396c4324ac7a42d147848943fc2) which should fix the problem.

Comment: I updated testcase with changed jquery.jqgrid.src.js from github but problem persists.

Comment: @Andrus: I made [some changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/437b319a231048f96c7fb09a6007ca413f5bf3ba) in the code of working with frozen columns in free jqGrid. I hope that the problem is fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. Now columns horizontal positions differ by few pixels as described in https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/52

Comment: @Andrus: Could you measure exactly **how many pixel difference** you have? You can see it very easy in Developer Tools.

Comment: @Andrus: I could reproduce the problem now. It's 3px difference. I suppose that you load some components of inline editing via Ajax. For example if you change the height of `Klliik0_engnimetus` items dynamically then jqGrid can't detect the changes. You have to trigger `jqGridResetFrozenHeights` explicitly in the case. Inline editing trigger the event, but it do this **directly** after starting inline editing. If you use `setTimeout(functsion() {...], 150)` and change the height of editing row 150ms later than jqGrid can't detect this. So you should trigger `jqGridResetFrozenHeights` manually.

Comment: If remitter column is removed, the issue does not occur. It looks like jquery ui autocomplete changes row height. How to fix this so that row height is not changed by autocomplete if inline edit starts ?